# Solution of ODE involving indicator fuctions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any method to find solutions to ODE of the form
$$-f(x)1(x>0)+f'(x)1(x>0)+af'(x)=h(x)-h(0)$$
with initial condition $f(0)=0$, where $h$ is some smooth function, $a$ is a constant and $1(x>0)$ is the indicator function of $x>0$. So we must have $f'(0)=0$ as well. Is there any general solution for this type of ODE. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Just solve it for $x>0$ and $x<0$, then match the solutions at $x=0$. For $x>0$ you have $f$ as an exponential convolved with $h(x)$, and for $x<0$ you have $f$ as an integral of $h$. Then apply your boundary (not initial) conditions.

Comment: For $x>0$ I guess the solution is $-e^{\frac{x}{1+a}}\int_x^\infty\frac{(h(y)-h(0))}{1+a}e^{\frac{-y}{1+a}}dy$. But for this $f'(0) \neq 0 $ right?

Comment: I believe you should integrate from $0$ to $x$. And yes, I think there is no reason to expect you'll have $f'(0)=0$ for arbitrary $h(x)$

Comment: So are you saying that the solution will not be differentiable at 0?

Comment: Not necessarily, I just think it's obvious you're not going to have a solution with $f'(0)=0$ if $h(x) = \delta(x)$, for instance. There is likely a constraint on $h$ needed for a solution meeting your requirements.